# dictionary to plot.bar with two values, one in y-axis another in x-axis with dict.key

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

dictionary to `plot.bar` with **two** data-set and one `dict.keys` show `x-axis` with **keys** `A,B,C,D,E,F,I,J,K,L,M,N` map with sorting values `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` , the example data sorting like this `N 1`, `B 2`", `C 3`, `D 4`, `E 5`, `I 6`, `F 7`, `J 8`, `K 9`, `L 10`, `M 11`, `A 12`
as **Expected bar chart**

**data-set**

```
x = {'A': ['12', '100'],
     'B': ['2', '101'],
     'C': ['3', '102'],
     'D': ['4', '103'],
     'E': ['5', '104'],
     'F': ['7', '105'],
     'I': ['6', '106'],
     'J': ['8', '107'],
     'K': ['9', '108'],
     'L': ['10', '109'],
     'M': ['11', '110'],
     'N': ['1', '111']}
```

**Expected bar chart**
[image: Expected bar chart]

**Tried Python Code: (with error)**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

# Dictionary loaded into a DataFrame       
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(x);
# Draw a vertical bar chart
dataFrame.plot.bar(rot=15, title="first record in bar second record in x-axis");
plot.show(block=True);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what error says the data is string so typecast it to int/float by `astype()` method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df=df.T.astype(int)
#If nan's are present in your dataset then typecast it to float
#df=df.T.astype(float)
#Since you only need to plot the second record so:
df[1].plot(kind='bar',title="first record in bar second record in x-axis")
```

[image]

OR

If you want like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(x)
df=df.T.astype(int)
df=df.set_index(0,append=True)
df=df.sort_index(level=1)
df.plot(kind='bar',title="first record in bar second record in x-axis",rot=20)
plt.legend(['second record'])
```

[image]

Comment: dear, thanks, but i expected like expected chart !

Comment: @Mary updated answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: dear, can i more dymanic, it seem have some problem when i add more records

Comment: @Mary I think that was because of `yticks` parameter passed so try removing that so it becomes `df.plot(kind='bar',title="first record in bar second record in x-axis",rot=20)`...updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the sorting values in the tickers than the following works:

```
x = {'A': ['12', '100'],
     'B': ['2', '101'],
     'C': ['3', '102'],
     'D': ['4', '103'],
     'E': ['5', '104'],
     'F': ['7', '105'],
     'I': ['6', '106'],
     'J': ['8', '107'],
     'K': ['9', '108'],
     'L': ['10', '109'],
     'M': ['11', '110'],
     'N': ['1', '111']}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(x).T
dataFrame.columns = ['level', 'value']
dataFrame = dataFrame.astype('int')
dataFrame.sort_values('level', inplace=True)
dataFrame['value'].plot.bar(title="first record in bar second record in x-axis")
```

Comment: dear, I need the sorting values, anyway, thanks !